# How can I submit a form on Enter key press without using jquery/javascript?

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, excel

The background into this question is I want to use asp.net mvc5 to create an MS Excel like spreadsheet presentation in an html table. Excel features are not part of this, just the look & feel. The pertaining features of Excel that I want to include in a web page are the user entering values into text boxes within a table row. To edit a row, they click on it and that turns table cells into cells with inputs/text boxes. They  enter their data and press enter (no links and no buttons) and that data is saved to the database. The input boxes are removed and the data is put in cells.

I've started on this project and have it working but I find myself using 50% javascript/jquery/html. My concern is I'm using too much ajax/javascript/jquery when I could simplify the design leveraging asp.net mvc.

I'm using ajax to send data and get data from the controller. The callbacks use jquery to create, update, delete rows in the table as well as changing from edit mode () to read mode ()

Because I use jquery for the ajax calls to the controller, all of the client code handling CRUD in the table is done via jquery.  Is mvc designed in such a way that we could use BeginForm in the cshtml template and send data from inputs in a table to the controller using FormCollection parameter on the press of the Enter key without using jquery?

Comment: I believe that this is the default behavior.  If you are inside of an input control, the enter might not submit, but I believe outside of that, Enter will submit a form.  This may be browser specific though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may be able to get away with adding a submit button to the form after the inputs, and then using css to set the position to absolute, and the left or top properties to large negative values, effectively making the submit button invisible while retaining it's default behavior of capturing ENTER key presses within the form.

On the other hand, I wouldn't worry too much about using Javascript unless you are seeing an actual performance or maintainability issue that you are addressing. Javascript is the most straight forward way to do this in my opinion, and doesn't appear to have a significant performance penalty.

Comment: I think if I keep most of the code on the server, what I build isn't ripped off so easily. The thief will have to work harder for it.

Comment: Answer marked because its helping (hidden input to trigger call to controller). I have another case where I need to call the controller. That is by an input of type select. How can I invoke a controller and action call when a user selects an item from an input?